# Hide a <li tab if a condition is met

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, yii, html-lists

I have a foreach look that checks if user has a picture or not. If the user doesn't have the picture I want to hide a `<li>` tab that shows the picture.

Inside my `else` how do I say, for this user hide tab 2?

I tried using `echo 'id="tabHeader_2" style:"visibility:hidden"`; but that doesn't work. I need a reference to that tab2, don't I?

```
<div id="picture<?php echo $i ?>" style="display: none;">
<?php
      $picture = $user->pic;
      if(isset($picture))
      {
         // show picture.           
      }
      else
      {
        // hide tab2
      }                   
  ?>    
 </div>
```

Then the list of tabs:

```
 <div class="profiles">
     <div id="tabContainer">
         <div class="tabs">
            <ul>
              <li id="tabHeader_1"> Profile </li>
              <li id="tabHeader_2"> Picture </li>
             </ul>
         </div>
         <div id="tabsContent">
              <div class="tabpage" id="tabpage_1"></div>
              <div class="tabpage" id="tabpage_2"></div>
         </div>
         <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/js/tabs.js"></script>
     </div>
 </div>
```

---

Picture of what the page looks like:

[image]

Comment: which is `tab1 tab2`?

Comment: `tabpage_2` and `tabHeader_2` correspond to tab2.

Comment: please do not use [bootstrap] as tag. that's another thing

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about your code, but you are using `isset()` which would not be correct, because you set the variable right behind that check so it will be set 100% of the time. You will want to check `empty()` or `is_file()` perhaps, depends on what is in that variable.

```
<!-- This display: none seems strange if you are going to show the wrapped elements -->
<div id="picture<?php echo $i ?>" style="display: none;">
<?php

      $picture = $user->pic;
      if(!empty($picture)) {
         // show picture.           
      }
      else {
        // hide tab2
      }                   
  ?>    
 </div>
```

If you put the real code, it would be easier to see how you are laying out your elements.

Answer (score -1):

Do Like This :-

```
<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
      <?php
      $i = 1;
      foreach($yourarray as $key => $value){
           if(isset($value) && $value != '')
           ?>
               <li id="tabProfileHeader<?php echo $i;?>"> Profile </li>
               <li id="tabPictureHeader<?php echo $i;?>"> Picture </li>
            <?php
         $i++;
         }
         ?>
     </ul>
</div>
```